# Magento Admin error CSS, jQuery, Image

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.1

My Magento Adminhtml error about CSS, jQuery, Image. My Frontend is still normal. Although I did deploy with my area is vi_VN but cannot fix this error.

This is my Adminhtml and Error:
[image: Adminhtml Error]

I did deploy:
[image: Deploy]

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands and check again

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US vi_VN
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: I have tried so many times but not this way. It seems the problem is not so simple.

Comment: You have to deploy both language. Have you try above all commands ?